# How to calculate max and min of multiple columns (row wise) using awk

Tags: unix, awk

This might be simple - I have a file as below:

df.csv

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
A,2,5,7,9
B,6,10,2,3
C,3,4,6,8
```

I want to perform `max(col2,col4) - min(col3,col5)` but I get an error using `max` and `min` in awk and write the result in a new column. So the desired output should look like:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,New_col
A,2,5,7,9,2
B,6,10,2,3,3
C,3,4,6,8,2
```

I used the code below but is does not work - how can I solve this?

```
awk -F, '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$(max($7,$9)-min($8,$10))}'
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by `max(col2,col4)` ?

Comment: so for the row one - the ```max(col2,col4)``` is 7. With this I mean to select the maximum number between the col2 and col4. with ```min(col3,col5)``` I mean to select the minimum value between the col3 and col5. At the end these values should be subtracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==1 {print $0, "New_col"; next} {print $0, ($2 > $4 ? $2 : $4) - ($3 < $5 ? $3 : $5)}' df.csv

col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,New_col
A,2,5,7,9,2
B,6,10,2,3,3
C,3,4,6,8,2
```

A more readable version:

```sh
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
NR == 1 {
   print $0, "New_col"
   next
}
{
   print $0, ($2 > $4 ? $2 : $4) - ($3 < $5 ? $3 : $5)
}' df.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{ print $0, (NR>1 ? max($2,$4) - min($3,$5) : "New_col") }

function max(a,b) {return (a>b ? a : b)}
function min(a,b) {return (a<b ? a : b)}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,New_col
A,2,5,7,9,2
B,6,10,2,3,3
C,3,4,6,8,2
```

If your actual "which is larger" calculation is more involved than just using `>`, e.g. if you were comparing dates in some non-alphabetic format or peoples names where you have to compare the surname before the forename and handle titles, etc., then you'd write the functions as:

```
function max(a,b) {
    # some algorithm to compare the 2 strings
}
function min(a,b) {return (max(a,b) == a ? b : a)}
```

Answer (score 0):

*get an error using `max` and `min` in awk and write the result in a new column.*

No such function are available in `awk` but for two values you might harness ternary operator, so in place of

```
max($7,$9)
```

try

```
($7>$9)?$7:$9
```

and in place of

```
min($8,$10)
```

try

```
($8<$10)?$8:$10
```

Above exploit `?:` which might be explained as `check?valueiftrue:valueiffalse`, simple example, let `file.txt` content be

```
100,100
100,300
300,100
300,300
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{print ($1>$2)?$1:$2}' file.txt
```

output

```
100
300
300
300
```

Also are you sure about 1st `$` in `$(max($7,$9)-min($8,$10))`? By doing so you instructed `awk` to get value of *n*-th column, where *n* is result of computation inside `(`...`)`.

Comment: could you please a bit elaborate about the way you suggested - at the end I want to have a single value which is the result of s subtraction of maximum value between col2 and col4 and the min value between the col3 and col5.